# Touch Gesture on a CALayer

Tags: objective-c, uiview, calayer, gesture, uigesturerecognizer

I am doing some drawing on a CALayer and want to be able to have the user single tap different parts of the drawing and trigger a response.  I tried looking into gesture recognizers, and it seems that they need to be tied to a UIView.  Any idea how I can get my desired behavior using CALayers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a responder to be able to respond to touches. From the view that is hosting this layer (at some point in your tree this needs to be true) you can use `-[CALayer hitTest:]` to try to find the deepest sublayer that will respond to you.